# At Least One Control of FormGourp is valid to enable submit form

Tags: angular, forms, form-control, formgroups

I have Two controls on my FormGroup I need at least one of two controls be validate to make possible submitting form

I need that formGroup valid  if only one FormControl is valid

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
        'keyWord' : new FormControl(null, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(4)
        ]),
        'name':  new FormControl(null, [
          Validators.required
 ])

      });
```

html

```
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="isPending=!isPending;searchCriteria(form.value);" class="form-group" novalidate>
        <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="?????">At Least One Field is required</small>
        <div class="input-group box-shadow">
            <div class="input-group-addon border-top-0 border-left-0 border-bottom-0 rounded-0">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="text" formControlName="keyWord" placeholder="" class="form-control border-0">
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="" class="form-control border-0">
            <button type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
```

Comment: mean this.form valid? or submit button enable?

Comment: yes button enable

Comment: That kinda contradicts with the validators. Both are required but your case says either is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="isPending=!isPending;searchCriteria(form.value);" class="form-group" novalidate>
            <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="?????">At Least One Field is required</small>
            <div class="input-group box-shadow">
                <div class="input-group-addon border-top-0 border-left-0 border-bottom-0 rounded-0">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" formControlName="keyWord" placeholder="" class="form-control border-0">
                <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="" class="form-control border-0">
                <button type="submit" value="submit" [disabled]="isvalid()">
          </form>
```

component function

```
  isValid(): boolean {
         if(this.form.get('keyWord').valid ||this.form.get('name').valid){
            retrun false;
         }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: isValid called on changes form ? every changes !

Comment: isValid called   synchronously. so if your form changed and both control invalid . button disable

Answer (score 1):

Make the disabled property of submit button as a function of form validity

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" [disabled]="(!form.get('keyWord').valid) && (!form.get('name').valid) ">
```

First off, we access specific form control using `<form name>.get('<member name>')`

Then, we use boolean logic as follows
All will be invalid at first, so disabled will be true because when they're invalid, valid is 0, and we negate it to 1.  so 1 || 1 = 1, if one is valid, then valid is 1, and !valid is 0, so we end up with 0 || 1 = 0, and we ignore the rest.

Comment: thanks for your answer but form.valid verify if my two controls are valid but me I need just one field valid to my form be valid

Comment: at least one control not all control of form